# How to call Thunderbird with a given profile when clicking a mailto: link

Tags: mailto, thunderbird

I always open my thunderbird with a -p option (added in the icon command line) to specify the path of the profile I want to use.
But if I click a mailto: link, the default thunderbird profile is used instead of my custom one.

Answer (score 1):

I found this working, with regedit change

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Thunderbird.Url.mailto\shell\open\command
```

Default value from

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe" -osint -compose "%1"
```

to

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe" -profile "<path_to_our_profile>" -compose "%1"
```

Perhaps change also in the same way :

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\shell\open\command
```

Apparently -osint and -profile are incompatible